# hibernate session to list conversion

Tags: scala

```
 hibernate session to list conversion
 Compilation Error occured when java converted into scala..!!
```

Error:
              type mismatch; found : java.util.List[?0] where type ?0 required: 
            scala.collection.immutable.List[com.scala.entity.User]

```
   Code:     def getAllUsers(): List[User] = {
          return getSession().createQuery("from User where reslut='false'").list()
           }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    def getAllUsers(): List[User] = {
    val objList = getSession().createQuery("from User where isDelete = 'false'").list()
    objList.asInstanceOf[List[User]]
```

Answer (score 2):

May be simply way to using scala.collection.JavaConverters:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def getAllUsers = getSession().createQuery("from User where reslut='false'").list().asScala.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[User])
```